# no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"

Tags: r, dplyr

Using the below code, I am trying to filter my dataset so that only those who are CG_less14==0 & CG_High14==0 to be selected. I got an error:  no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')". Is something wrong with my code?

`married_noncare <-  filter (all_sample, CG_less14==0 & CG_High14==0)`

Comment: Check `class(all_sample)`. It is likely numeric, instead of a data.frame or tibble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that the columns are `factor`..  One option is to convert to numeric or characteer

```
library(dplyr)
filter(all_sample, as.character(CG_Less14) == 0 & as.character(CG_High14) == 0)
```

---

Or with `filter_at`

```
all_sample %>%
      filter_at(vars(CG_Less14, CG_High14), all_vars(as.character(.) == 0))
```

Comment: Thanks. I got an error: Evaluation error: operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types. But this one worked: married_noncare <-  filter (Diss, as.numeric(CG_less14==0) & as.numeric(CG_High14==0))

Comment: @NaderMehri can you please update your post with `dput` of a small example.  Here, I am assuming that you have a `data.frame/tbl_df/data.table` etc

Comment: This command worked: married_noncare <- filter (Diss, as.numeric(CG_less14==0) & as.numeric(CG_High14==0))

Comment: @NaderMehri I think that would be not correct, because you are converting the logical to numeric (`as.numeric(...)` and then do the `&` i.e. converting again to logical

Comment: @NaderMerhri Suppose you have `v1 <- c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1); v2 <- c(0, 2, 0, 1, 1); as.numeric(v1 == 0) & as.numeric(v2 == 0)` would give the same output as `(v1 == 0) & (v2 == 0)`, but I can imagine some cases this could have an issue